# Is there a master list of gpt type codes?

Tags: partitioning, gpt

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) on GPT lists a few dozen codes, but I've found some that are not on the list (especially by dumping an Android partition table).

Is there a master registry of these codes?

Also, do the individual file system types (e.g. ext4, f2fs) have their own values, or do they all fall under "Linux filesystem data"?

Comment: [They are generated at the time of need](http://betterexplained.com/articles/the-quick-guide-to-guids/)  so no there will never be a master table

Comment: Sure, but don't they get registered somewhere once generated? The model, as I understand it, is that the id field is generated when the partition is created, but the **type** value is generated just once, when the partition type is invented, at which point it would make a lot of sense to advertise it.

Comment: People rarely do anything that makes sense.